# For each, if any empty: no whitespace

Tags: php

I'm working with a `foreach` loop. If condition returns empty, it should `echo` something. But I was getting the opposite effect. I am trying to make sure the POST actually contains data, and not just `whitespaces`. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
     $transponame = $_POST['transponame'];
     $transpoid = $_POST['transpoid'];

     foreach( $transponame as $key => $n ) {
         $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
         $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
         $n = mysql_real_escape_string($n);
         $n = htmlentities($n, ENT_QUOTES);
         $transpoid[$key] = htmlentities(strip_tags($transpoid[$key]),ENT_QUOTES);
         if (!empty($n) && !empty($transpoid[$key])) { 
             echo "its empty";
         }  

     } 
?>
```

Comment: change !empty($transpoid[$key]) to !empty($key)

Comment: If you want to see if it's truly empty, `trim()` the `$_POST` and see if it's empty after that.

Comment: Also, you'd want to see `if(empty()` not `if(!empty()` otherwise it will be the opposite as you mention if it's not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable with `white space` is not empty. So you have to `trim` the value.

```
<?php
$transponame = $_POST['transponame'];
$transpoid = $_POST['transpoid'];

foreach( $transponame as $key => $n ) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
    $n = mysql_real_escape_string($n);
    $n = htmlentities($n, ENT_QUOTES);
    $transpoid[$key] = htmlentities(strip_tags($transpoid[$key]),ENT_QUOTES);
if (empty(trim($n)) || empty(trim($transpoid[$key]))) { 
echo "its empty";
};  

} ?>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Also, to help other people in case they have the same issue I updated part of the code that I messed up on!